# Number of edge states as Topological Invariant

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators

Can anyone please direct me to some sources which provide some definite rigorous proofs for the fact that the number of edge states ($N_A-N_B$ in case of SSH Model) is a topological invariant

Comment: Yes or maybe. See http://theorie.physik.uni-konstanz.de/burkard/sites/default/files/ts15/TalkSSH.pdf

Comment: Actually I have already looked into this book. I was searching for a more mathematically rigorous proof of it

Comment: @Souradeep It is easy to define a bulk topological invariant. Are you happy with that aspect? If so, do I understand correctly that you are essentially asking about the bulk-boundary corresponence? (I.e., why the rigorous bulk invariant coincides with the number of edge modes?)

Comment: In a way, yes. But what I'm looking for is the rigorous proof that the number of edge states is a topological invariant in its own right. The bulk boundary correspondence is a further higher result